# No "Baseline Profile Generator template" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, baseline-profile

[image]I am trying to use Baseline Profile Generator to generate baseline profile for my app, but there is no Baseline Profile Generator module in Templates.

following is my building environment:

OS: ubuntu 18

android studio version: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1

AGP: 8.2.1

Does anyone know how to import Baseline Profile Generator into Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is available from Android Studion Iguana which is in canary, its mentioned here,

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/create-baselineprofile#create-new-profile

I am currently using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 18.
To download preview versions : https://developer.android.com/studio/preview